# Compiling existing C++ project to DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll

I'm working on an inherited project that includes a C++ project which is successfully compiled to .exe. Now I want to try and integrate this project to a .NET form so I want to have it as a DLL (from what I've read it seems easier to do that if I use dll instead of exe) so I want to compile my C++ project to .DLL. I tried by right clicking on the project and making adjustment on the properties, but even though I choose .dll option when I rebuild the project I still get exe file.

Comment: Which project properties did you change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the three "cleanest" options:

1. Create a [C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163852.aspx) (also called "Mangaged C++) wrapper around your C++ code to expose the functions as class methods.  Then you can call these methods from C# just as you would a C# class.
2. Create a COM wrapper around your C++ functions.  Very similar to creating a CLI wrapper, but can be used in non-.NET environments as well (VBA, for example)
3. Call your C++ DLL using [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx).  This requires the least C++ coding but can also tricky to get the interop correct, especially if you're marshaling structures or other complex data types.

Answer (score 1):

You need at least to change

- General/Configuration Type
- Linker/General/Output File

But your DLL should implement DllMain to ensure that the runtime initialization is done properly.

Another approach might be creating a new DLL project and adding all code from the EXE. This makes the project wizard script running the appropriate lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use COM Interop to integrate C++ classes with .NET framework.

Comment: Three techniques for achieving this and you recommended the most complicated, without further details?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio it's easiest to take the path of least resistance. Just create a new empty DLL project, add your source files to it, change the C++ details (under Properties) and voila! Trying to change the project settings by hand always seems to leave a lot of redundant chaff in there.

Under Code Generation you probably want Multi-threaded (Debug) DLL